# Wordpress query post order via alternate subfield

Tags: wordpress, repeater, custom-fields, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF PRO's Repeater feature which allows for one or multiple subfield within a single post. I am utilizing this feature so that content editors can assign multiple dates to a post with an assigned priority level (high=1 and low=0) for each date.

The code below queries for posts that have an assigned date matching todays date. **Then I want to order the posts so that the assigned date priority level 1 posts are listed first.** Everything works as expected but when I have posts with more than one assigned date/priority level, the query just utilizes the first priority value it gets, not just the priority value which is assigned to the specific (today's) date.

**I somehow need to identify the row # the assigned date is from so that I can only utilize the priority value from that sub-row. Any help would be amazing! Thank you in advance!**

---

If you're not familiar with ACF Repeater feature, they use a three-part naming convention for repeating sub-fields:

1. main-custom-field-name
2. row#
3. sub-field-name

OR main-custom-field-name_row#_sub-field-name

---

```
<?php

function my_posts_where( $where ) {
    $where = str_replace("meta_key = 'ssm_assign_%", "meta_key LIKE 'ssm_assign_%", $where);
    return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'my_posts_where');


$datetoday = current_time('Ymd');
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'=> 2,
    'post_type'     => 'ssm',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'          => 'AND',
        'assigned_dates'    => array(
            'key'               => 'ssm_assign_%_ssm_assigned_date',
            'compare'           => '=',
            'value'             => $datetoday,
        ),
        'assigned_priorities' => array(
            'key'               => 'ssm_assign_%_ssm_date_priority',
            'compare'           => 'EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
    'orderby'       => 'assigned_priorities',
    'order'             => 'DESC',

);
// query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $the_query->have_posts() ):

    // Start the loop.
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();    
        include(locate_template('content.php'));
    endwhile;
    // End the loop.
        get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
    endif; //End of customized current day posts

wp_reset_query();    // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().

?>
```